# jQuery - overwriting events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

My page contains some drag-able `div` elements ( **not** jQuery UI dragable ).

Now we want to add a new feature: the user should be able to select more than one `div` at a time and drag these `div` elements without triggering the previous bound events.

Now here is my problem:

Is it possible to disable the `mousedown`, `mousemove` and `mouseup` event of each `div` as long as they are part of a selection?

So basically I want to **replace** the **old event** by a new one and **afterwards restoring** the original events.

Thanks for your time

---

Update:

I wrote a tiny script to test `stopImmediatePropagation`

[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/odafi)

With the following code:

```
$("p").click(function(event){
  alert ( ' I am the old event ' );
});

$("a").click( function()
{
  
   $("p").click(function(event){
     event.stopImmediatePropagation();
     alert ( ' I am the new event ' );
   });


return false;
});
```

It does not work as `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` is called after the first event.
So the out put is:

> I am the old event
>
> I am the new event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a look at `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`.

See here in the [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.stopImmediatePropagation.28.29)

Basically you make one function optionally block the other functions from running - you don't need to remove and rebind the functions.

---

Here's your code from JSBin that I've modified to make it work. It's a bit hacky and probably not very efficient, but it works!

```
$("p").click(function(event){
  alert ( ' I am the old event ' );
});

$("a").click( function() {
  $("p").each(function() {
    var $t = $(this);
    var events = $t.data("events");
    $t.unbind('click');
    $t.click(function(event){
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      alert ( ' I am the new event ' );
    });
    for (var i = 0, l = events.length; i < l; ++i) {
      $t.click(events[i]);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. This is exactly what I was searching for.
However it does not work. See my updated post for details.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just `unbind()` the event?

See the [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/unbind)